.Net Aspire dashboard not loading after publishing (it shows An unhandled error has occurred. Reload)
I am just playing around with .Net Aspire. I have published the default starter application. When I am trying to access the dashboard it's not loading. I can access the dashboard locally but published on is not working.
In the browser console, it's giving the below error.

Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so
this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed
exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in
'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'.

I followed this question as well but it didn't help. I am new to the blazor as well. so pardon me if it's an obvious question.


I'm having the same issue. The starter template dashboard operates fine locally, but deploying to Azure results in the exception. I can't seem to trace how the dashboard is being hosted in Azure to be able to find logs to debug.

I believe the .NET Aspire's orchestration is primarily focuses on enhancing the local development experience by simplifying the management of your cloud-native app's configuration and interconnections. I am not sure it meant to deploy on Prod or Test enviroments. Read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/aspire/get-started/aspire-overview

@ChinmayT,
Agreed. The Aspire Dashboard is primarily for improving local development.
But, MS does seem to want to support it hosted in Azure. See here, here, and here (last link seems to indicate it's no longer in alpha despite docs at first two links).

I had the same error initially too, and was able to resolve it by the following:

Go to your webfrontend project in Azure portal, and find the .NET Aspire Dashboard on the Overview page -> click "settings":



On the settings page, toggle the .NET Aspire Dashboard (which should currently be "Enabled") to disable it, and save.



Go back to the main dashboard page, and refresh, until it shows the .NET Aspire dashboard as not yet enabled. Now you can enable it again.



Go back to the main page, and refresh, until it shows the .NET Aspire dashboard as running again. At this point I suggest closing your browser, as I remember seeing that it may not run first time that your browser is open.

Launch the .NET Aspire dashboard from the link again, and it should be running successfully now.



Ah. The turn it off and back on approach. Nice. My instance of this issue magically started working again, but I'll try this approach if it occurs again. It'd be nice if we could see logs in Azure of the Dashboard app itself.

Yes, likewise I tried every approach I could to enable the DetailedErrors for the dashboard, but couldn't find anything to give me any more details on the dashboard exception. So thankfully it started working after this!

@CollinBarrett same for me as well, it started working by itself after some time when I checked. But reason still I don’t know
